# PHP INI Array with Variable Variable

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I have a name value pair in a settings.ini:

```
[Server1]
ServerName=Joe
ServerIP=1.1.1.1
ServerPort=1111
[Server2]
ServerName=Schmoe
ServerIP=2.2.2.2
ServerPort=2222
```

I have read it in using the nifty ini parser.

I have a while loop to cycle through each but I can't get it to assign the variable variable:

```
while($checkeachserver < server_count)
        {
    $servernumber = 'Server'.$checkeachserver;
    $serverip = $ini_array.$servernumber[ServerIP];
    $serverport = $ini_array.${$servernumber}[ServerPort];
    print_r($serverip);
         $checkeachserver++
```

}

Both of these return "Array"

Help?

Comment: you need to post the code you are using

Comment: It would `[Server1]` is an array e.g `$var['Server1']['ServerName']` = `Joe`

Comment: Variable variables are like this: `${'Server' . $checkeachserver}`

Comment: better to keep the array than use nasty variable variables.

Comment: print_r($ini_array[Server1][ServerIP]); << this produces the desired result ... I'm trying to cycle through n quantity of servers in a loop. How do I 'keep an array'??

Comment: well `$ini_array` is a variable you can use like any other, why do you need to duplicate its contents and make another variable?

Answer (score 0):

Completely refactored as follows:

```
foreach($server_array as $item) {

            $serverip = $item['ServerIP'];
            $serverport = $item['ServerPort'];
            $servername = $item['ServerName']; }
```